# Weird narrowing conversion double to float warnings in g++ compiler

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, implicit-conversion, narrowing

I have this function for creating a vector from polar notation which uses braced initializer in it:

```
// Constructs a 2D vector from XY-coordinates.
inline vector2(float x, float y) : x_(x), y_(y) { }

// Constructs a 2D vector from polar coordinates
static vector2 polar(float r, float phi) {
    return {r * cos(phi), r * sin(phi)};
}
```

In MSVS all seems fine, but g++ compiler shows warnings that for me seems rather weird:

```
vector2.h:37:23: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘(((double)r) * cos(((double)phi)))’ from ‘double’ to ‘float’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
             return {r * cos(phi), r * sin(phi)};
                     ~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

If I use constructor warning disappears:

```
// Constructs a 2D vector from polar coordinates
static vector2 polar(float r, float phi) {
    return vector2(r * cos(phi), r * sin(phi));
}
```

Why does this warning appear? Does it mean that a compiled program will do an unnecessary conversion from `float` to `double` and back to `float`?

**UPDATE**
Here is minimal reproducible example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Pair {
public:
    float x_;
    float y_;

    inline Pair(float x, float y) : x_(x), y_(y) {};

};

Pair braced(float a) {
    return {a * 2, cos(a) * 3};
}

Pair constr(float a) {
    return Pair(a * 2, cos(a) * 3);
}

Pair stdbraced(float a) {
    return {a * 2, std::cos(a) * 3};
}

Pair stdconstr(float a) {
    return Pair(a * 2, std::cos(a) * 3);
}

int main() {
    float x = 2.0;
    auto a = braced(x);
    cout << a.x_ << ' ' << a.y_ << endl;
    auto b = constr(x);
    cout << b.x_ << ' ' << b.y_ << endl;
    auto c = stdbraced(x);
    cout << c.x_ << ' ' << c.y_ << endl;
    auto d = stdconstr(x);
    cout << d.x_ << ' ' << d.y_ << endl;
}
```

Output of `g++ test.cpp -o test`:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘Pair braced(float)’:
test.cpp:15:27: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘(cos(((double)a)) * (double)3)’ from ‘double’ to ‘float’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
         return {a*2,cos(a)*3};
                     ~~~~~~^~
```

So using `std::cos` do help. But the main question remains (and bothering me) - why warning appears only when using braced initialization?

Comment: vector2 seems to be a constructor. How is the class defined? You should provide a minimal Reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you would post the whole source code.

From what you have posted I assume you don't have something like

```
using namespace std;
```

So `cos()` and `sin()` are the old C versions. They both expect an input of type `double`. `cosf()` and `sinf()` are the function expecting a float. Since you are using c++ you want to use the STL functions and not the old C ones.

So do the following

```cpp
static vector2 polar(float r, float phi) {
    return {r * std::cos(phi), r * std::sin(phi)};
}
```

The STL functions are overloads so they take float and double as input, without any implicit conversions.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct `cos` and `sin`

```
#include <cmath>

class vector2 {
public:
float x_, y_;
// Constructs a 2D vector from XY-coordinates.
inline vector2(float x, float y) : x_(x), y_(y) { }
};

// Constructs a 2D vector from polar coordinates
static vector2 polar(float r, float phi) {
    return {r * std::cos(phi), r * std::sin(phi)};
}
```

Using the `std::cos` and `std::sin` gives the correct result as they are overload like [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/cos/):

```
double cos (double x);
float cos (float x);
long double cos (long double x);
double cos (T x);           // additional overloads for integral types
```

Edit:
Running it in [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sMtWHp) Just give the same warning, but pressing the [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/cd282ea9) button gives the more correct error:

> /home/insights/insights.cpp:17:20: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'double' to 'float' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
>       return {a * 2, cos(a) * 3};
>                      ^~~~~~~~~~
>   /home/insights/insights.cpp:17:20: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
>       return {a * 2, cos(a) * 3};
>                      ^~~~~~~~~~

Which then lead to the definition of [initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) which mentions [list-initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) and the subsection "narrowing"

> Narrowing conversions
>   list-initialization limits the allowed implicit conversions by prohibiting the following:

- conversion from a floating-point type to an integer type
- conversion from a long double to double or to float and conversion from double to float, except where the source is a constant expression and overflow does not occur
- conversion from an integer type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value can be stored exactly in the target type
- conversion from integer or unscoped enumeration type to integer type that cannot represent all values of the original, except where source is a constant expression whose value can be stored exactly in the target type

So if I read that correctly it should have been an error.

Comment: @gazand Edited with better diagnostic.